# Deployed ASP.Net WebApp via public github repo, is there any way to hide the connection string?

Tags: asp.net-core, github, azure-devops, devops, github-secret

Ideally, I would like to keep my repo public, but the connection string contains sensitive information. Is there any way to hide the string?

I was thinking I could store the connection string in GitHub Secrets, but that would leave the question of how to access the value from the program.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a development version of the normal appsettings.json file, named `appsettings.Development.json`. And hide it using .gitignore.

You can add connection string in `appsettings.Development.json`.

> Tip:
> Please check if the structure of the appsettings.json and the appsettings.Development.json are the same. It maybe has a issue with that the template of both files where not the same.

Then we can create `.gitignore` file in the root directory. Add the following lines of code at the bottom.

```
# Config files
appsettings.Development.json
```